# Vector Subspace involving polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$H=\{p(x)\in P_2|p(1)=0\}$ is a vector subspace of $P_2$. What is a basis for $H$ and the $\dim(H)$? I think the dimension is $0$ since the restriction of $p(1)=0$, is that wrong because it is a polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Note that $x-1 \in H$, and $x^2 - 1 \in H$. So $H$ is at least 2-dimensional (as $x-1$ and $x^2 - 1$ are linearly independent). Can $H$ be 3-dimensional? Note that $\dim P_2 = 3$!